# Remove the ability to view strategic databases from a user

Tags: mysql

I have a user who has access to several databases on a mysql server i.e.mysql db, information_schema db, test db etc

Is it possible to restrict access from this user such that a "`SHOW DATABASES`" command will not even list these strategic dbs?

Answer (score 1):

By default all users can see an `information_schema` table.  It is not a real table but more like a collection of read only views. For each user it only shows values for tables and objects that the user has access rights to.  If your users are accessing via phpMyAdmin it can be hidden by adding a line in the config file. Something like this...

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^information_schema$';
```

Also by default MySQL allows all users to see the database named "test" and any database that begins with "test_".  These behaviors are controlled by lines in the `db` table of the `mysql` database. Search that table for entries in the `Db` field that begin with "test" and you will see them. They have "%" in the `Host` field and a blank `User` field. For more information you can look at section 2.10.2. "Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts" of the MySQL docs under the heading "Securing Test Databases" on this page...  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html.

Answer (score 0):

Per the MySQL show databases documentation:

You see only those databases for which you have some kind of privilege, unless you have the global SHOW DATABASES privilege. You can also get this list using the mysqlshow command.

If the server was started with the --skip-show-database option, you cannot use this statement at all unless you have the SHOW DATABASES privilege.

MySQL implements databases as directories in the data directory, so this statement simply lists directories in that location. However, the output may include names of directories that do not correspond to actual databases.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `Show_db_priv` for it

The SHOW DATABASES privilege enables the account to see database names by issuing the SHOW DATABASE statement. Accounts that do not have this privilege see only databases for which they have some privileges, and cannot use the statement at all if the server was started with the --skip-show-database option. Note that any global privilege is a privilege for the database.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases